# Assigning to a member with `as` in context-manager (with) and exception handler

Tags: python, exception, with-statement

First of all I would like to apologise if I don't use the right names for things, I'm new to Python.

While playing around I found out that you can assign to a class member in the `as` part of a `with` statement:

```
from contextlib import contextmanager

@contextmanager
def func(val):
    yield val*2

class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.val = "Placeholder"

    def bar(self):
        with func(333) as self.val:
            print("Got", self.val)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    f = Foo()
    print("Before:", f.val)
    f.bar()
    print("After:", f.val)
```

Output:

> Before: Placeholder
>   Got 666
>   After: 666

However, assigning to a member in an `except` gives me a syntax error:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.err = None

    def bar(self):
        try:
            os.remove(path)
        except FileNotFoundError as self.err:
            print("Couldn't remove", path)
```

Output:

> ```
> except FileNotFoundError as self.err:                                      
>                                 ^
> ```
>
> SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Since searching for `as` is an exercise in futility I wasn't able to find any reference on this, my questions are:

1. Is it well defined to assign to a member in the `as` part of a `with` statement?
2. If so, how come it's not allowed in exception handling?

**Edit**: I suppose a similar question can be asked about `import`...

Comment: I have no idea what the answer is, but this is a really interesting question!

Comment: Note that ``as`` is not a separate operator, but a part of the respective statement. It means different things in ``import ... as ...``, ``except ... as ...`` and ``with ... as ...``.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi, I see, the semantics are similar though. (also, Wax on, Wax off).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In an [`except` clause](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-try-statement), `as` can only assign to an identifier. In a [`with` clause](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement), `as` can assign to an arbitrary target.

> ```
> try1_stmt ::=  "try" ":" suite
>            ("except" [expression ["as" identifier]] ":" suite)+
>            ["else" ":" suite]
>            ["finally" ":" suite]
>
> with_item ::=  expression ["as" target]
> ```

A [target](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#grammar-token-target) is an identifier (`foo`), an attribute (`foo.bar`), a slice (`foo[:bar]`), a subscription (`foo[bar]`), a list/tuple of the above (`foo, bar`) or a splat of the above (`*foo`).

---

Exceptions are automatically cleared after their exception handler. Using the name after a handler shows that it is removed:

```
>>> a = 1
>>> try:
...     1/0
... except ZeroDivisionError as a:
...     pass
... print(a)
NameError: name 'a' is not defined
```

This avoids unwanted reference cycles between the exception, the frame in which it was thrown, and the name binding the exception.

Directly binding to another namespace would require choosing one of two situations:

- The attribute is deleted after the handler. This means the outward appearance of the object is not consistent.
- The attribute is not deleted after the handler. This means the frame lives on indefinitely unless manually cleared.

Both variants require explicit handling of the exception outside the handler. Moreover, they make it easy to accidentally trigger a situation that requires explicit handling elsewhere.

Comment: Thanks, does this mean that I can use assignment to members in `with` statements and it's not just a quirk of the version of Python I'm using?

Comment: @Motti I have added the respective grammar definitions. Yes, you can rely on doing attribute assignments using ``with ... as ...``.